# Removing "yo" from my autocorrect

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I'm using Android 4.4.2 on my Galaxy S4 and using keyboard layout Icecream Sandwich.  I want to program my phone that when I incorrectly type yo that it autocorrects "to".  I don't recall when it stopped doing this, but it is very frustrating to be saying yo all of the time because of fat fingers.

Comment: *Hussain's* answer should work out. As an alternative, this app [Swiftkey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey&hl=en) automatically detects the typos and also learns from your typing on its own, no need to program it.

Answer (score 0):

You must have accidentally disabled the auto correct option under your keyboard settings. 
Go to Language and input --> select your preferred keyboard and goto its settings --> search for the auto correct checkbox and mark it to true.